# Google Drive API doesn't allow more then 2GB of file transfer per day

Tags: google-drive-api

I have built an application for our client which lists files and folders from Google Drive account. Where staff member can add, remove and search through. Everything is working fine but there is 2GB of daily limit of file transfer. Is there any way to increase that limit?

Comment: possibly share the files to one or more Service Accounts and use their credentials to access the files.

Comment: Thanks @pinoyyid for swift response. I am afraid, will that work as we need API access credentials. Will each user use their own credentials, if so is there any way to filter shared files of specific account?

Comment: it will be for you to decide how many service accounts to create and how to allocate credentials to users. I suggest start by experimenting with one to see if allows you to get beyond the 2GB limit.